# Удаление одинаковых элементов в двух двумерных массивах

Tags: php, массивы, алгоритм

Есть два массива.

Первый:

```
array(3) 
{ 
    [0]=> array(7) 
        { 
            [0]=> string(19) "2018-12-13 22:48:44" 
            [1]=> string(3) "Nissan" 
            [2]=> string(3) "Cefiro" 
            [3]=> string(3) "1995" 
            [4]=> string(8) "Black" 
            [5]=> string(8) "25000" 
            [6]=> string(5) "баксов" 
        } 
    [1]=> array(7) 
        { 
            [0]=> string(19) "2018-12-13 22:48:44" 
            [1]=> string(3) "Nissan" 
            [2]=> string(3) "Teana" 
            [3]=> string(3) "2000" 
            [4]=> string(8) "Gold" 
            [5]=> string(8) "250000" 
        } 
    [2]=> array(7) 
        { 
            [0]=> string(19) "2018-12-13 22:48:44" 
            [1]=> string(3) "Nissan" 
            [2]=> string(3) "Blueberd" 
            [3]=> string(3) "1997" 
            [4]=> string(8) "White" 
            [5]=> string(8) "10000" 
            [6]=> string(5) "баксов" 
        } 
}
```

Второй:

```
array(4) 
{ 
    [0]=> array(7) 
        { 
            [0]=> string(19) "2018-12-13 22:48:44" 
            [1]=> string(3) "Nissan" 
            [2]=> string(3) "Cefiro" 
            [3]=> string(3) "1995" 
            [4]=> string(8) "Black" 
            [5]=> string(8) "25000" 
            [6]=> string(5) "баксов" 
        } 
    [1]=> array(7) 
        { 
            [0]=> string(19) "2018-12-13 22:48:44" 
            [1]=> string(3) "Nissan" 
            [2]=> string(3) "Z350" 
            [3]=> string(3) "2006" 
            [4]=> string(8) "Red" 
            [5]=> string(8) "1050000" 
            [6]=> string(5) "баксов" 
        } 
    [2]=> array(7) 
        { 
            [0]=> string(19) "2018-12-13 22:48:44" 
            [1]=> string(3) "Nissan" 
            [2]=> string(3) "Silvia" 
            [3]=> string(3) "2006" 
            [4]=> string(8) "Black" 
            [5]=> string(8) "350000" 
            [6]=> string(5) "баксов" 
        } 
    [3]=> array(7) 
        { 
            [0]=> string(19) "2018-12-13 22:48:44" 
            [1]=> string(3) "Nissan" 
            [2]=> string(3) "Blueberd" 
            [3]=> string(3) "1997" 
            [4]=> string(8) "White" 
            [5]=> string(8) "10000" 
            [6]=> string(5) "баксов" 
        } 
}
```

в результате должен получится массив:

```
array(3) 
    { 
        [0]=> array(7) 
            { 
                [0]=> string(19) "2018-12-13 22:48:44" 
                [1]=> string(3) "Nissan" 
                [2]=> string(3) "Teana" 
                [3]=> string(3) "2000" 
                [4]=> string(8) "Gold" 
                [5]=> string(8) "250000" 
        [1]=> array(7) 
            { 
                [0]=> string(19) "2018-12-13 22:48:44" 
                [1]=> string(3) "Nissan" 
                [2]=> string(3) "Z350" 
                [3]=> string(3) "2006" 
                [4]=> string(8) "Red" 
                [5]=> string(8) "1050000" 
                [6]=> string(5) "баксов" 
            } 
        [2]=> array(7) 
            { 
                [0]=> string(19) "2018-12-13 22:48:44" 
                [1]=> string(3) "Nissan" 
                [2]=> string(3) "Silvia" 
                [3]=> string(3) "2006" 
                [4]=> string(8) "Black" 
                [5]=> string(8) "350000" 
                [6]=> string(5) "баксов" 
            } 
    }
```

как удалить одинаковые элементы и оставить разные в одном массиве?

- Одинаковые это все значения вложенного массива, если значения вложенного массива совпадают со значениями другого вложенного массива, то они удаляются.
  типа это все одно целое, и если есть в другом вложенном массиве это же то удаляется оно

  ```
          [0]=> string(19) "2018-12-13 22:48:44" 
          [1]=> string(3) "Nissan" 
          [2]=> string(3) "Silvia" 
          [3]=> string(3) "2006" 
          [4]=> string(8) "Black" 
          [5]=> string(8) "350000" 
          [6]=> string(5) "баксов"
  ```

Comment: вам их надо поэлементно сравнивать? типа элемент из первого массива с соответствующим элементов второго?

Comment: Перед тем, как задачу делать, её следует понять. Это важное условие. Если задача непонятна, то её невозможно решить. В данном случае в задаче отсутствуют условия, которые позволяют её решить. Так что вам надо сначала понять свою задачу, а потом сформулировать её заново.

Comment: Или, если сложности с формулировками, то хотя бы привести пример  массива, который надо получить в итоге.

Comment: Да, и если эти данные получены из базы, то все надо делать средствами SQL

Comment: @Ипатьев чисто работа с массивами, поправил вопрос.

Comment: вы словами можете описать вопрос, чтобы никто не гадал, что значит разные и т.п.?

Comment: А куда должен деться Blueberd?

Comment: @Ипатьев это вхождение есть в обоих массивах, как и bluebird.

Comment: @teran посмотрите пожалуйста, все ли я нормально описал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас имеются два массива, вида

```
$a = [ ['date1', 'a', 'b'], ['date2', 'c', 'd']];
$b = [ ['date1', 'a', 'x'], ['date2', 'c','y']];
```

и вам нужно поэлементно их сравнить, и удалить совпадающие значения, то есть получить

```
$result = [['b','x'], ['d','y']];
```

то вам в помощью функции `array_map`, `array_merge` и `array_diff`, в любом, угодном вам сочетании

```
$result = array_map(function($a, $b){
                return array_merge(array_diff($a,$b), array_diff($b,$a));
            }, $a, $b);
```

если при этом нужно сохранить поле, содержащее дату, то в `merge` следует добавить `[$a[0]]` либо `[$b[0]]`, раз уж они предположительно одинаковы.

---

upd: склейте массивы в строку, найдите строки без повторов, разделите обратно

```
$map = function($v){ return implode("|", $v); };

$a = array_map($map, $a);
$b = array_map($map, $b);

$result = array_merge(array_diff($a,$b), array_diff($b,$a));
$result = array_map(function($v){ return explode("|", $v);}, $result);
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но если один из двух массивов больше то возникает такая ошибка array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array. Так же немного поправил вопрос.

Comment: @MaximLyubitelev я дополнил ответ, если что